# Google sheet automatically generate a pdf and send an email to notify

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, google-sheets-api

I need to write a script that allows me to automatically save a pdf after the data has been refreshed and send people an email.
The current problem is that there are too many columns in the google sheet(from A to AZ) and we need all the columns in the pdf.
In download as pdf, we have the option to set it as normal and split
[image]

[image]

Is it feasible in appscript?

```
function refreshAndSendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx');
  const tabsToSnapshot = ['a', 'b']; // Replace with the names of the tabs you want to snapshot

  tabsToSnapshot.forEach(tabName => {
    const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabName);
    if (dataSheet) {
      refreshDataSourcesForSheet(dataSheet);

    } else {
      console.log(`${tabName} not found.`);
    }
  });

  const pdfBlob = generatePDF(ss);
  sendEmailWithAttachment(pdfBlob);
}

function refreshDataSourcesForSheet(sheet) {
  const dataSources = sheet.getDataSourceTables();
  dataSources.forEach(dataSource => {
    dataSource.refreshData();
    console.log(`Last refresh time for ${dataSource.getName()}: ${dataSource.getStatus().getLastRefreshTime()}`);
  });
}


function generatePDF(ss) {
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    // "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };


  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const pdfBlob = response.getBlob().setName('Snapshot.pdf');
  return pdfBlob;
}

// function setPrintArea(sheet, printAreaRange) {
//   const range = sheet.getRange(printAreaRange);
//   sheet.setActiveRange(range);
//   const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//   spreadsheet.setNamedRange('Print_Area', range);
// }


function sendEmailWithAttachment(pdfBlob) {
  const recipient = 'email'; // Replace with the recipient's email address
  const subject = 'Snapshot of Data';
  const body = 'Please find the snapshot of data attached.';
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export a Spreadsheet without fitting the width of the sheet to the page. Namely, when some columns are more than one page, you want to put them on the next pages.

If my understanding is correct, how about modifying `fitw=true` to `fitw=false` as follows?

#### From:

```
"fitw=true&" +
```

#### To:

```
"fitw=false&" +
```

#### Note:

**In this modification, it supposes that your current script works fine. Please be careful about this.**

If your function `generatePDF` is modified, it becomes as follows.

```js
function generatePDF(ss) {
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=false&" + // <--- Modified
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    // "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };


  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const pdfBlob = response.getBlob().setName('Snapshot.pdf');
  return pdfBlob;
}
```

#### References:

- [exportSpreadsheet.gs by Spencer-Easton](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70)
- [exportSpreadsheet.gs by andrewroberts](https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb)

Comment: @Skylar Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.